# Comparing most recent InnoDB_Rows_Inserted variable value with old value

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-administration

This is the query that I have written:

```
SELECT variable_name,0 - variable_value 
  FROM information_schema.global_status 
 WHERE variable_name IN ('Innodb_rows_inserted','Innodb_rows_updated'
                        ,'Innodb_rows_deleted','Innodb_rows_read'
                        ,'Innodb_data_reads','Innodb_data_read'
                        , 'Innodb_data_writes','Innodb_data_written');
+----------------------+--------------------+
| variable_name        | 0 - variable_value |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| INNODB_DATA_READ     |           -6672384 |
| INNODB_DATA_READS    |               -422 |
| INNODB_DATA_WRITES   |                -22 |
| INNODB_DATA_WRITTEN  |            -333312 |
| INNODB_ROWS_DELETED  |                  0 |
| INNODB_ROWS_INSERTED |                 -2 |
| INNODB_ROWS_READ     |                -17 |
| INNODB_ROWS_UPDATED  |                  0 |
+----------------------+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I want the difference between the most recently updated value for `INNODB_ROWS_INSERTED` and its last value.

For example - In the above output, value of `INNODb_ROWS_INSERTED` is 2. If I make one more insert and re run this query, the updated value will be 3. Now I want to display the difference, i.e. 1 in a new table or a file.

Thanks

Comment: retrieve value, save it, do you stuff, retrieve value again, compare it. but note that those values are SYSTEM-WIDE. if any other queries execute in parallel, they'll also affect the values.

Comment: Beware that Innodb_rows_inserted has been removed from MariaDB as of 10.10

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the [Observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)).

Plan A:  Put the original values in a temp table, but make sure it is not an InnoDB table.  After the test, `JOIN` the `information_schema` query to it to get the diffs.

Plan B:  Use `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb%'` before and after; parse the ouput (in, say, PHP); take the diffs.  It seems that `SHOW` is less likely to be subject to the Observer effect.  But the coding is more clumsy.

Plan C (won't work for *those* `STATUS` values):  `FLUSH STATUS` zeros out *some* `STATUS` values.  Do that before the test, then use `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE '...'` afterwards.  (Note use of `SESSION`.)  This works well for `LIKE 'Handler%'`, which I find useful in digging into how queries work and how fast or slow they are.